# The return statement is throwing out an undefined value for a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to solve this question-> 
https://www.codewars.com/kata/541c8630095125aba6000c00/train/javascript

Basically the purpose of the function is to:
16  -->  1 + 6 = 7 
942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6 
132189  -->  1 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 8 + 9 = 24  -->  2 + 4 = 6 
493193  -->  4 + 9 + 3 + 1 + 9 + 3 = 29  -->  2 + 9 = 11  -->  1 + 1 = 2

I am able to get the correct answer ("final sum") in my console.log but I am not able to get that value in the written statement.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  console.log("initial", n)
  let sum=0
  
  while(n>0){
    
    sum+= n%10
    console.log("sum",sum)
    n= Math.floor(n/10)
    console.log("num",n)
    
  }
  if(sum>10){
    digital_root(sum)
  } else{
      console.log("final sum",sum)
      return sum}
}
```

Here's the console.log->

```
initial 16
sum 6
num 1
sum 7
num 0
final sum 7
initial 195
sum 5
num 19
sum 14
num 1
sum 15
num 0
initial 15
sum 5
num 1
sum 6
num 0
final sum 6
```

```
initial 398754
sum 4
num 39875
sum 9
num 3987
sum 16
num 398
sum 24
num 39
sum 33
num 3
sum 36
num 0
initial 36
sum 6
num 3
sum 9
num 0
final sum 9
```

its returning undefined instead of 6 & 9 respectively.

Also a humble request is to not suggest an alternative solution but to help me fix this one.
Thank you

Comment: Your function doesn’t return anything when `if(sum > 10){ digital_root(sum); }` is executed.

Comment: You have to use return statement in if statement too 
function digital_root(n) {
  console.log("initial", n)
  let sum=0
  
  while(n>0){
    
    sum+= n%10
    console.log("sum",sum)
    n= Math.floor(n/10)
    console.log("num",n)
    
  }
  if(sum>10){
    return digital_root(sum)
  } else{
      console.log("final sum",sum)
      return sum}
}

Comment: I know you didn't want an alternative, but just for fun I made a simple + elegant way to do it: `function g(num) { return (function t(a) { let c = a.toString().split("").reduce((prev, cur) => prev + +cur, 0); if(c.toString().length === 1) { return c; } return t(c); })(num.toString()); }`.

Comment: @AsadHaroon 
I found an even more elegant way->
```md
function digital_root(n) {
  return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
}
```